# How to autohide div on a set of timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a flash message on my app, like this:
[image]

and here is the snippet of my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function delete_flash(flash){
        $(flash).parent().remove()
    }

</script>
```

and here is the div that I want to automatically hide:

```
<div class="ui {{ class }} message">
    <i class="close icon" onclick="delete_flash(this)"></i>
       {{ msg }}
</div>
```

On that code above, I can close the flash message when I click the close icon. But for now, I want to hide that message automatically after set a timeout time, let say in 5 seconds it will hide automatically.

Please, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** For more informations, I following this flash message from this Flask [boilerplate](https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/blob/master/app/templates/partials/_flashes.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of, don't use `.parent()` one day it might not be a parent any more and your JS will fail miserably. Use the `.closest('selector')` Method.
- Don't use inline JS `onclick="delete_flash(this)"`
- For accessibility reasons use `<button>` instead of `<i>` (or at least use the Aria `role="button"` attribute)
- Use `data-autohide="5"` (or any other number) on your message elements.

I'd suggest a **better way** instead, the other way around, **using events**

```js
$('.message').each((i, el) => {

  const $el = $(el);
  const $xx = $el.find('.close');
  const sec = $el.data('autohide');
  const triggerRemove = () => clearTimeout($el.trigger('remove').T);
  
  $el.one('remove', () => $el.remove());
  $xx.one('click', triggerRemove);
  if (sec) $el.T = setTimeout(triggerRemove, sec * 1000);

});
```

```css
.message {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 1em;
  font: bold 16px/1.4 sans-serif;
  color:            hsl(100, 50%, 40%);
  background:       hsl(100, 95%, 95%);
  border: 2px solid hsl(100, 70%, 70%);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.message .close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
}

.message .close:after {
  content: '\2716';
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui message" data-autohide="5">
  Successfully added Python course
  <button type="button" class="close icon"></button>
</div>

<div class="ui message" data-autohide="3">
  I will disappear after 3 sec!
  <button type="button" class="close icon"></button> 
</div>

<div class="ui message error">
  I hide only on X click
  <button type="button" class="close icon"></button> 
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://api.jquery.com/one/
https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Perfect answer, very like it, especially on `data-autohide` attribute, we can set the timeout there. Very thanks Man :)

Comment: hi @Roko C. Buljan, could you explain what the .T syntax is..?

Comment: @Harvest1018 Since `$el` is just an Object (jQuery, OK, but it's an Object) `T` is just a dummy property we assign to that Object in order to store the timeout: `$el.T = setTimeout( ...`. That way we can later do `clearTimeout($el.T)` when needed - ohh, and since it's jQuery we can beforehand use any jQuey method like `trigger()` and than access the `T` value : `clearTimeout($el.trigger('remove').T)`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by calling `$(flash).parent().remove();` inside of a callback function passed to [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

The `setTimeout()` method will call the function you provide after the number of milliseconds specified. Passing 5000 as the second argument would cause the element to be removed after 5 seconds:

```
function delete_flash(flash){

     /* 
     If no deleteTimer exists for this element then create one 
     */
     if(!$(flash).data('deleteTimer')) {

       var seconds = 5;

       /* 
       Creating the timer for this element which will remove the parent 
       5 seconds from now 
       */
       var timer = setTimeout(function() {
          $(flash).parent().remove();
       }, seconds * 1000);

       /* Store timer with element to prevent multiple timers */
       $(flash).data('deleteTimer', timer);
     }

}
```

Note that in the case of your code, you should guard against `setTimeout()` being called multiple times (ie after the first timeout is created) to prevent multiple timeout timers from running concurrently. One solution would be to store the first timer as a temporary data attribute on the `flash` element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout` with a `5000ms` delay.

```
function delete_flash(flash) {
  $(flash).parent().remove()
}

setTimeout(delete_flash, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
function delete_flash(flash){


       setTimeout(function() {
         $(flash).parent().remove()
       }, 1000);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setTimeout() method in javascript.

```
function delete_flash(flash){
    var timeOut = 3;
    if(!$(flash).data('deleteTimer', timer)){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(flash).parent().remove();
        }, timeOut*1000);
        $(flash).data('deleteTimer', timer);
    }
}
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)